# Solve a PDE related to free boundary problem

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, linear-pde, parabolic-pde

I would like to solve the following system for my problem:

$$\max\Big(\frac{1}{2}u_{ss}+u_l\delta(s-s_0), F(l)-\lambda(s)-u(s,l)\Big)=0.$$

where $u=u(s,l): R\times R_+\to R$ is the unknown function and $F: R_+\to R$, $\lambda: R\to R$ are given functions. Suppose that $F$ and $\lambda$ are sufficiently regular and $F$ is convex.

I guess that there exists some domain $D\subseteq R\times R_+$ charaterized by $\gamma_+$ and $\gamma_-$:

$$D=\big\{(s,l): l> 0, \gamma_-(l)<s<\gamma_+(l)\big\},$$

such that

$$\frac{1}{2}u_{ss}+u_l\delta(s-s_0)=0 \mbox{ and } u\ge F-\lambda \mbox{ on } D,$$

and

$$u= F-\lambda \mbox{ on } D^c,$$

where $\gamma_+$ and $\gamma_-$ are determined later. I suggest a solution given by

$$u(s,l)=a(l)(s-s_0)^++b(l)(s-s_0)+c(l)$$

and add boundary conditions and smoothing conditions, i.e.

\begin{eqnarray}
u(\gamma_{\pm}(l),l)&=& F(l)-\lambda (\gamma_{\pm}(l)), \\
u_s(\gamma_{\pm}(l),l)&=&-\lambda' (\gamma_{\pm}(l)).
\end{eqnarray}

And I find formally that $u$ defined above solves the system by calculating $a$, $b$, $c$ and $\gamma_{\pm}$. Now my question is:how to solve the previous system if we replace $F(l)$ by $F(s,l)$. Thx a lot for answer!